# Python : starting background process from background process

Tags: python, flask, background-process

I'm having a bit of an issue, and my many tests/searches have led me nowhere so far.

I have a Flask application giving a GUI for a small alarm system running on a raspberry pi.
The GUI allows to start the alarm (motion sensors on the GPIO pins, for now) as a background process. This runs fine, in case of a detection it sends an email.
I'm trying to add a method that will play a siren sound (or a black metal song at 100 db, haven't decided yet :p ).
The method itself is in a class and works fine, I can activate/deactivate it as another background process from the GUI.

However, I am unable to have it triggered automatically by the alarm process. Not sure why, I have no error, it just doesn't fire:

```
class Alarm(Process):

  def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      self.exit = Event()


  def shutdown(self):
      self.exit.set()

  def run(self):

      Process.__init__(self)

      #code
      #if motion detected sendmail, and run the siren:

      siren = Siren()  #actually, problem here: I need to import the class 
                       #and declare this in the main Flask app file, so as 
                       #to be able to control it from the GUI. Apparently I 
                       #can't declare it in both python files (sounds 
                       #obvious though)
      siren.start()

      #then keep looping
```

and the Siren class is similar:

```
class Siren(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):

        Process.__init__(self)

        #code using pyaudio
```

I'm guessing my very basic understanding of classes and methods is the culprit here.
I've also tried to use events, so instead of `siren.start()` I'd have something like `e = Event()` and `e.set()`, but I couldn't manage to run the Siren class in the background and have it pick that event up with `e.wait()`.

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be calling `Process.__init__` from `Alarm.run`!  You are already doing that in `Alarm.__init__`

`Process.__init__(self)` is exactly the same as `super().__init__()`

**update**

Does this help:

```
import threading
import time

class Alarm(threading.Thread):



    def run(self):

        #code
        #if motion detected sendmail, and run the siren:

        siren = Siren()  #actually, problem here: I need to import the class 
                         #and declare this in the main Flask app file, so as 
                         #to be able to control it from the GUI. Apparently I 
                         #can't declare it in both python files (sounds 
                         #obvious though)
        siren.start()


        #then keep looping
        for x in range(20):
            print ".",
            time.sleep(1)
        siren.term()
        siren.join()



class Siren(threading.Thread):

    def run(self):

        self.keepRunning=True;

        while self.keepRunning:
            print "+",
            time.sleep(1)

    def term(self):
        self.keepRunning=False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    alarm = Alarm()
    alarm.run()
```

output:

```
+. + . .+ . + +. +. . + . + . + . + + . + . + . + . + . + . + . + . +. +. +
```

Comment: ok, that was one fault. I removed `Process.__init__`from both classes. However, there is no change on the behavior.. when `siren` is triggered by the Alarm process itself, `siren.is_alive()` returns `True`, but it isn't executed in reality. It just goes to the next statement, without any error or warning.

Comment: @Jackson_DKMG, I added some code that uses threading.Thread just because that's what I'm used to doing.  Does it work in your Flask environment?

Comment: Thanks, it might actually help. I'll test that over the week-end !

Comment: Actually; this new issue is out of the scope of the initial question. I'll mark your answer as a valid solution, and will open a new subject if I really can't make it work. Thanks!

Comment: (my comment above was irrelevant, I deleted it)

Comment: Are you thinking that there is something about Flask that is preventing threading from working?

Comment: I'm not sure, but as a matter in fact, it doesn't work : I can start the thread allright with the button click, but stopping it does not work... the term() function is executed on the button click (as per the debug in PyCharm), but the while loop continues as the value of `keepRunning` remains true. For now, I really can't understand why this happens, I'm searching through other similar posts. I've tested other methods such as using `threading.Event()` but no luck either. I'm on Windows, so I'll try on a debian, but I doubt it can be OS-dependent anyway.

Comment: Can you put your code on the cloud somewhere so that I can look at it?  I'm currently creating Flask applications with background tasks.  Maybe, I can see something obvious.

Comment: Yes, I'll post the relevant classes, flask route and the html code tomorrow, I'll figure where to put that and will post the link here

Comment: ok so, I put the concerned code in a jsfiddle. Not exactly appropriate, but it shows the two python files and the html/jquery code on a single page (no point trying to execute it though): https://jsfiddle.net/Jackson_DKMG/dpjag8mm/1/

Comment: wait - sorry, that's all wrong, it can't work like that obviously

Comment: ok, phew. After too many edits, I hadn't noticed it was completely broken anyway. Really need to install a git or something to keep track of changes. Anyway, here's the "working" version : https://jsfiddle.net/Jackson_DKMG/dpjag8mm/2/   The stop function is called, but the loop keeps going... i don't quite get why.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2yu1suf8/  I've made changes to your code.  I haven't actually run this but... I think that you have two problems:  One your global variable sirenRunning probably isn't actually shared between the two processes.  Two, you need to wait for the thread to terminate after you call stop.

Comment: so, -- no, it doesn't work either. You are probably spot on regarding the global variable, but I couldn't find a solution. As per waiting for the thread to stop, placing a `siren.join()` after the stop doesn't have any effect. I've asked the question on the #pocoo IRC channel, and it seems that I'm just not supposed to do that with Flask... I should use a task queue and a message broker. I'm going to try and integrate Celery and Redis, I think. Here I was, wanting to build a simple app :'( ... Anyway, many thanks for taking the time to try and assist, much appreciated. Cheers.